# Segmentation fault in linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list

Below is my program, I have tried several methods but I am not able to come on conclusion, stuck due to it, can anyone help?

What's wrong and Any alternative ways to go with?

```
struct Node
    {
        int data;
        struct Node *prev,*next;
    };
```

Inserting the elements

```
   void push(struct Node *start,struct Node *end,int x,int loc)
    {
        struct Node *new=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        new->data=x;
        if(start==NULL)
        {
            new->next=NULL;
            new->prev=NULL;
            start=new;
            end=new;

        }
        else 
        {
            if(loc==1)
            {
                new->prev=NULL;
                new->next=start;
                start->prev=new;
                start=new;
            }
            else
            {
                struct Node *ptr=start;
                for(int i=0;i<loc-1;i++)
                {
                    ptr=ptr->next;
                }
                if(ptr->next==NULL)
                {
                    new->next=NULL;
                    new->prev=ptr;
                    ptr->next=new;
                    end=new;
                }
                else
                {
                    new->next=ptr->next;
                    new->prev=ptr;
                    ptr->next->prev=new;
                    ptr->next=new;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Displaying from start

```
void display_start(struct Node *temp)
        {
            struct Node *ptr=NULL;
            for(ptr=temp;ptr->next!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next)
            {
                printf("%d\t",ptr->data);
            }
           printf("%d",ptr->data);
        }
```

Displaying from end

```
        void display_end(struct Node *temp2)
        {
            struct Node *ptr=NULL;
            for(ptr=temp2;ptr->prev!=NULL;ptr=ptr->prev)
            {
                printf("%d\t",ptr->data);
            }
            printf("%d",ptr->data);
        }
```

Main Function

```
        int main(void) {
            // your code goes here
        struct Node* head=NULL;
        struct Node* tail=NULL;

        push(head,tail,1,1);
        push(head,tail,2,2);
        push(head,tail,3,2);
        push(head,tail,4,3);
        push(head,tail,5,5);
        push(head,tail,6,4);

        printf("From Start: ");
        display_start(head);
        printf("From End: ");
        display_end(tail);
            return 0;
        }
```

One compiler is displaying a **garbage value** and the other one is showing **Segmentation fault**

As far as I know the error is coming while displaying the list.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. Improve it, and repeat all. BTW compilers don't show segmentation fault: it is your program which shows it. And StackOverflow is not a fix-my-bug site, so your question is off-topic here.

Comment: Read more some C programming book. It uses call-by-value, so changing a formal don't affect the calling argument

Comment: Okay Basile, I am new to SOF and will keep these things in mind from next time! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause of `display_start()` not printing the list is, you have pass the  `head` to `push()` function which is treated as call by value in C. So whatever modification you do with `head` in `push()` function will not get affect in `main()` function and list will be still empty.

Instead of passing just `head` to `push()` function, pass the address of `head`, same applicable for `tail` also.

For e.g

`push(&head,&tail,1,1);`

And do the respective changes in `push()` function.

`void push(struct Node **start,struct Node **end,int x,int loc) {`

`/* Do changes here */`

`}`

Also compile your program with `-Wall` flag like `gcc -Wall test.c` and don't ignore warning, solve them. Better treat all warnings as error by compiling with `-Wstrict-prototypes -Werror` so that there could be less chance of bugs. for e.g

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c
```

And finally learn how to debug a small code https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/